# Filling a course array with course information

Tags: java, arrays

So, I have Students.java and TestStudents.java. I'm suppose to create 3 student objects and then assign them 3-5 classes with (courseName, creditHours, and letterGrade) and then print out a average of the grades of the 5 classes. I create the students, but what I'm lost on is filling the array with course information tied to each student. I think I developed a weak spot with arrays, I understand using a loop to fill it - but what are the parameters of the loop AND how do I make the array specific to each student?

The other challenge I'm having is I haven't been told exactly what the Course class is doing, only that it's necessary and obviously contains the computeGPA method

```
import codelibraries.chp10.Course;
public class Students
{
  private String _fname;
  private String _lname;
  private Course[] _carry;
  private int _numCourses;

  public Students(String first, String last, int NumCourses)
  {
  _fname = first;
  _lname = last;
  _numCourses=NumCourses;
  _carry = new Course[NumCourses];
  }

  //THIS IS WHERE IM LOST
  public void createCourse(String courseName, int creditHours, char letterGrade)
  {
  Course tempCourse = new Course(courseName, creditHours, letterGrade);
  _carry[] = tempCourse;
  }

  public String toString()
  {
  return "Student " + _fname + " " + _lname + " has a  " + Course.computeGPA(_carry) + " GPA"; 
  }


}
```

MAIN PROGRAM

```
public class TestStudents
      {
      public static void main (String[] args)
      {

  Students Jane = new Students ("Jane", "Doe", 5);
        Jane.createCourse("Math", 4, 'A');
        Jane.createCourse("English", 3, 'A');
        Jane.createCourse("CS", 4, 'A');
        Jane.createCourse("Chemistry", 3, 'B');
        Jane.createCourse("Health", 2, 'B');

        //Automatically calls toString
  Students John = new Students ("John", "Smith", 5);
  Students David = new Students ("David", "Hill", 3);


  System.out.println(Jane);
  System.out.println(John);
  System.out.println(David);
  }
 }
```

This is a route I'm trying but I really don't know.

```
public void createCourse(String courseName, int creditHours, char letterGrade)
  {
  Course tempCourse = new Course(courseName, creditHours, letterGrade);

  int i = 1;
  if (_carry[i]!=null){
  i++;
  }
  _carry[i] = tempCourse;
  }
```

Comment: I find it ironic that your homework programming question is about students with coursework.  By the way, it is very kinky to have your Java variable names begin with an underscore `_`.

Comment: My professor said he did it to establish private class members, beats me.

Comment: I agree.. the naming conventions you are using are not regular naming conventions. They look like C# conventions.. but not even like those..

Comment: Just keep an index into the course array and increment it by one each time you add a new course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign a value to the 1st unassigned index in the array like this:

```
for( int i =0; i< _carry.length; i++) {
    if(_carry[i] == null) {
        _carry[i] = course;
        break;
    }
}
```

Using arrays for this is not ideal though. If you have a variable length list of items a List is better suited because you can just add more items to it.

Comment: Thank you, that's more or less what I needed. I got it working. I didn't realize in the process of doing this that by using ConstructorName.createCourse (Jane.CreateCourse) that the instance of the array was limited to that constructor. Weird to get my head around

Comment: **Jane** is the name of the variable, it should be **jane**. Also **CreateCourse** would be better named **addCourse**. You might also want to consider creating the Courses outside of the Student class and pass it as a parameter to the create/add method. :)

Comment: You can have **static** methods that are not instance related and should be called using the class name. In your case Student.myStaticMethod

Comment: btw, if you're ok with my reply please mark it as the answer. :)

Comment: Unfortunately some of what you're talking about is already defined by the professor. CreateCourse must be CreateCourse. I do see what you're saying about Jane/jane though

Comment: pity, those are not standard naming java naming rules. These are: http://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions